# PS4 remote lock program/service (custom program)

Tags: service, ps4

I am trying to create a service that will allow me to enable or disable a Play Station 4 remotely, kind of like a lock screen.

I would be able to program it, the problem is I found nothing on the matter of making custom programs for the console, the closest I got is that I need to use Unreal engine for making a game for the console but that's about it nor their environment.

I never made any program/game for a console before so I don't even know how to start this, any directions or links would help.. google is giving me nothing on this matter at all.

The idea is:
a set up pf multiple PS4 consoles for public use but for limited times per user, so it needs a way to timer them and lock them when needed via LAN.. the TVs aren't smart so I can't do much there, so my best attempt is through the console it self, where a service will be installed and connected to a desktop/phone app where he can control them.

If there is another suggestion of doing this then please do advise.

P.S.

I believe the PS4 are pre-cracked, so Sony's DevKit won't be needed I think... not well informed on this matter either.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pre-cracked' ? It's not possible to install any such custom software on vanilla PS4's (you need a PS4 devkit). There's no current exploit that exists for bypassing the PS4 security either and installing your own software (as was recently found for the Nintendo Switch).

Comment: @auburg , I had a feeling this might be the case.. but I did hear the are bringing a cracked consoles for the place, and with a quick search it seems PS4 with firmware v4.5 is crack-able.. if that was the case would it be possible?

Comment: I would have thought  Sony's lawyers wouldn't take too kindly to SO if code was posted that targets cracked PS4's !